# Add image overlay to video to replace head

Tags: video

I want to replace a person's head with one of three static images (left/right/front view) in a video, without editing every single frame. I have no problem with the result looking amateurish and cheap (because it is).

I managed to get my sound synchronized with the video using blender, but I wasn't able to find  a way to import my three pictures and show them where they would fit. I'll need to re-size them and move them quite a bit, it would be great if I can do this without preparing the different sizes in advance.

I'm not married to blender, any software that is free for non-commercial use will be fine. 
I'll gladly accept a lmgtfy, I ran out of keywords to find what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is known as [motion tracking](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=motion%20tracking). While it's more often used to integrate 3D elements with live footage, I think it'll suit your needs here.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Motion_Tracking_with_Icarus